# linq compiled query error "parameteres cannot be sequences"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've got the code below:

```
var catRoots = CatalogContext.CatalogRoots.Where(cr => cr.Visible);
var catChapter = CatalogContext.CatalogChapters.Where(cch => cch.Visible);
var catThemes = CatalogContext.CatalogThemes.Where(cth => cth.Visible);
var catCompanies = CatalogContext.CatalogCompanies.Where(cc => cc.Visible);
var catRelations = CatalogContext.CatalogCompanyThemeRelations.Where(cctr => cctr.Visible && cctr.OwnerVisible);
var regions = CatalogContext.Regions.AsQueryable();

var compChapters = catRelations.Where(cctr => cctr.Location == CatalogCompanyLocations.Chapter)
            .Join(catChapter, cctr => cctr.ParentID, cch => cch.ID, (cctr, cch) => new { Relation = cctr, Chapter = cch })
            .Join(catRoots, cch => cch.Chapter.CatalogRootID, cr => cr.ID, (cch, cr) => new { CatalogRoot = cr, CatalogChapter = cch.Chapter, CatalogRelation = cch.Relation })
            .Join(catCompanies, cr => cr.CatalogRelation.CompanyID, cc => cc.ID, (cr, cc) => new { Root = cr.CatalogRoot, Chapter = cr.CatalogChapter, Theme = default(CatalogTheme), Company = cc })
            .Join(regions, cc => cc.Company.RegionID, r => r.ID, (cc, r) => new { Root = cc.Root, Chapter = cc.Chapter, Theme = cc.Theme, Company = cc })
            .GroupBy(gr => new { Chapter = gr.Chapter, Name = gr.Root.Name, ID = gr.Root.ID, Icon = gr.Root.Icon, Rewrite = gr.Root.Rewrite, Sort = gr.Root.Sort })
            .Select(gr => new { Chapter = gr.Key.Chapter, ID = gr.Key.ID, Name = gr.Key.Name, Icon = gr.Key.Icon, Rewrite = gr.Key.Rewrite, Sort = gr.Key.Sort, Count = gr.Count() });

var compThemes = catRelations.Where(cctr => cctr.Location == CatalogCompanyLocations.Theme)
            .Join(catThemes, cctr => cctr.ParentID, cth => cth.ID, (cctr, cth) => new { Relation = cctr, Theme = cth })
            .Join(catChapter, cth => cth.Theme.CatalogChapterID, cch => cch.ID, (cth, cch) => new { Relation = cth.Relation, Theme = cth.Theme, Chapter = cch })
            .Join(catRoots, cch => cch.Chapter.CatalogRootID, cr => cr.ID, (cch, cr) => new { Relation = cch.Relation, Theme = cch.Theme, Chapter = cch.Chapter, Root = cr })
            .Join(catCompanies, cr => cr.Relation.CompanyID, cc => cc.ID, (cr, cc) => new { Root = cr.Root, Chapter = cr.Chapter, Theme = cr.Theme, Company = cc })
            .Join(regions, cc => cc.Company.RegionID, r => r.ID, (cc, r) => new { Root = cc.Root, Chapter = cc.Chapter, Theme = cc.Theme, Company = cc.Company })
            .GroupBy(gr => new { Chapter = gr.Chapter, Name = gr.Root.Name, ID = gr.Root.ID, Icon = gr.Root.Icon, Rewrite = gr.Root.Rewrite, Sort = gr.Root.Sort })
            .Select(gr => new { Chapter = gr.Key.Chapter, ID = gr.Key.ID, Name = gr.Key.Name, Icon = gr.Key.Icon, Rewrite = gr.Key.Rewrite, Sort = gr.Key.Sort, Count = gr.Count() });

var source = compChapters.Union(compThemes);

var chapters = source.Select(r => new { Chapter = r.Chapter, Count = r.Count }).Cast<object>().Distinct();

public static Func<DataContext, IQueryable<object>, IEnumerable<object>> filteredFunc = 
CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, IQueryable<object>, IEnumerable<object>>
(
      (DataContext db, IQueryable<object> q) => q.Distinct().ToList()
);

filtredChapters = filteredFunc(CatalogContext, chapters);
```

I'm getting an error "parameteres cannot be sequences" when I run filteredFunc, which is weird, because "chapters" object is IQueryable, not IEnumerable, so why am I getting the error?

The code below works fine, but it is not good for me.

```
filtredChapters = chapters.Distinct().Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: What part of this are you trying to compile? It looks like you're querying the database to populate `chapters` then trying to pass the results of that back to the database to use distinct. Do you know which line the database read actually happens? I suspect it's the `var chapters` line and that's not what you meant. I've only every used CompiledQueries to start from a set taken from the DataContext rather than using a set passed in.

Comment: try create IEnumerable from your IQueriable using toList function. be aware it will pass database query

Comment: Rup, there is a sequence of queries which are joined between each other, I updated my post with the these queries. It seems like you are right that queries shouldn't be passed in to the CompiledQuery, anyway I thought it would decrease time for evaluating only one query, not all the queries, but it is strange that we can't pass queries. Will reconsider my queries.

Comment: ASpirin, this will take a lot of time to evaluate query to IEnumerable, as this query has over 40 000 rows of data and every time the page loads it take about 4 secs for evaluating. So that why I try to implement the CompiledQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use compiled queries with an IEnumerable like this. The number of items in the enumeration can vary and so the query plan for the query will vary based on its size. Just remove the compiled query and use the function as is.